# Is there an explanation for Natsu's motion sickness?

Tags: fairy-tail

In Fairy Tail, Natsu is prone to getting sick whilst on modern transport. I am asking this question because it kind of annoys me when he gets motion sickness while fighting someone on board train or other forms of transport. These are the known forms of transport that he gets sick on such as...

1. Cars
2. Trains
3. Vehicles
4. ... And many and all forms of transport that moves.

   I think an exception to his motion sickness is when he is flying on Happy, but can't really think of anything else that he doesn't get motion sickness on.
5. And waves, just discovered in Episode 133 (quite strange).

Generally, he gets motion sickness from all non organic transportation. He also gets motion sickness when riding on other people. He is also known to get sick from looking or thinking about all different forms of transport, e.g. looking or thinking about trains.

Was it ever explained in the anime or manga why Natsu suffered from motion sickness? And why did Wendy's motion sickness spell not work at all? Did something happen to Natsu in his life that made him suffer from motion sickness? If *yes*, please include it in the answer! Also, please refrain from using the reason **"Natsu built up immunity to Wendy's motion sickness spell"** in your answer, unless that's all you can possibly give me.

Answers are kindly appreciated.

Comment: It's a disadvantage of having Dragon Slayer magic. This is confirmed in episode 161 - Chariot - by String, Rogue, Laxus, Gajeel and Natsu. They all have the sickness. The reason why Wendy doesn't have it, is what Sting said to Gajeel, who noticed the sickness for the first time. When you become a "real" DS (read: strong enough), you gain the sickness. That's why Gajeel didn't have this during the S-class tournment. Laxus confirmed that it also doesn't matter whether you are a 1st, 2nd or 3rd generation DS, they all have it.

Comment: Also, Wendy's magic *does* work as was shown previously. It just loses it's effectiveness the more it is used due to the immunity that is built up. That's why she only wants to use it in situations that matter.

Comment: Personally, I find the Lucy Sickness the most hilarious!! +1 Happy. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not only Natsu, but every wizard having Dragon Slayer Magic is prone to motion sickness. During the Grand Magic Tournament, all four Dragon Slayers suffered from motion sickness, i.e. Natsu, Gajeel, Rouge, and Sting. It is also confirmed in the anime that, Laxus suffers from motion sickness as well. The only exception is Wendy, but considering that she has Magic to counter motion sickness, it might not be affecting her.

It has not been explained, but it is likely due to a side effect of the Dragon Slayer Magic.

Wendy's Magic does not affect Natsu because he built up immunity. This was specifically stated by Wendy herself.

Also, Happy doesn't affect Natsu because Natsu doesn't consider Happy as a vehicle. This was also specifically mentioned by Natsu.

**Edit as per the latest chapter:** The motion sickness is caused due to inability of dragon slayer magic holder to adjust with the dragon's enhanced visual acuity which affects their semicircular canals.

> [image]

Comment: Are you sure it is a side effect of dragon slayer magic. I have only so far seen Natsu who has displayed having motion sickness. In the Wizard Tournament it was probably a one off, but Natsu has it all the time.

Comment: not actually sure as not mentioned anything regarding that anywhere till now. but in the tournament gazeel says that he didn't have motion sickness but generates motion sickness after the tournament. so there might be some threshold point after which it affects dragon slayers. and natsu being hero of series must be powerful enough to have crossed that point.

Comment: Addition to your answer @Sp0T, I am guessing it has something to do with age as a Dragon Slayer, because Laxus is actually affected by it as well as said in the anime during the grand magic games. So theoretically it might be every single dragon slayer that is affected like how every devil fruit user cannot swim in One Piece

Comment: Wouldn't they be able to get around this weakness by closing their eyes?

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to [Sp0T's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7959/is-there-a-explanation-for-natsus-motion-sickness/7960#7960), it seems like they have to be in a more advanced level of Dragon Slayer Magic to experience motion sickness. Just like Gajeel in Phantom Lord arc with their moving guild, and in Tenrou Island arc when they get to the Island by ship, he doesn't seems to have problem with motion sickness. However, just after his three month training for Grand Magic Tournament, he gets motion sickness.

Answer (score 2):

In real life, motion sickness is caused by mixed signals from your senses, i.e. your eyes tell you the train isn't moving, as you are moving with it, however, your sense of balance feels all the bumps and swaying and tells you that you are moving. The result is confusion leading to nausea.

Putting that into the context of Fairy Tail, Dragon Slayers are shown to have heightened senses, Natsu more so than the others, probably because he is strong. So my guess is, stronger senses means stronger mixed signals and stronger motion sickness.

Answer (score 0):

Sting said that when you become a real dragon slayer, you start to suffer the motion sickness. Maybe Wendy doesn't have it because she's not at that level yet, which means that Natsu has been a strong dragon slayer since the beginning and was stronger than Gajeel up until the episode 161 *Chariot*.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, so I just edit and remove the part that doesn't make sense from your answer.